# run python script with subprocess fails on ImportError

Tags: python, subprocess

My files' tree is something like:

```
package1\
    __init__.py
    parent_script.py
package2\
    __init__.py
    child_script.py
    module.py
```

I'm trying to execute `child_script.py` as a subprocess from `parent_script.py`.

`child_script.py` uses import from `package2.module.py`:

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)
from package2.module import func1, func2
```

I'm getting `ImportError: No module named..` when running `child_script.py` as a subprocess, **but it runs well independently.**

Where am I wrong?

Comment: can you tell how you are importing module.py things from child_script

Comment: @SachinRajput, I've updated the question.

Comment: just do from module import func1, func2 because you are in same directory as child_script.py

Comment: it solved the fail! thanks! but why does it run well independently?

Comment: if you don't mind can you upVote then

Comment: it runs well independently...that i didnt understood ...what do you mean by that

Comment: if I run `child_script.py` itself (not as subprocess), it doesn't fail.

Comment: Try this from .. import package2.module  with subprocess..and let me know the what happens

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on my linux machine. Can you post the full traceback? Python wouldn't print `ImportError: No module named..` so I suspect its been abbreviated. Also, can you `print(sys.path)` after the insertion has been made? And let us know what the current working directory was in both cases?

Comment: @SachinRajput - I got `ImportError: cannot import name ..`

Comment: @tdelaney - in both cases current directory is package2. and after after re-checking - I'm getting ImportError:  `No module named..` and it's the whole traceback.

Comment: How are you running the script as a subprocess? Please add the code to your question.